# Eclipse Post build step with command 'scp' should prompt for password

Tags: eclipse

I want to configure a post build step that copies the binary via ssh:

```
scp MyProgramm root@192.168.2.113:/bin
```

I remember having done smth like that before and I was asked for the root password by a Dialog Box in eclipse!
Does anyone know if I need to put smth else in the textfield?
Or how can I pass the password? `echo password | scp...` does not work...

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the soultion:

```
bash -c "scp MyProgram root@192.167.1.111:/bin/"
```

Now What I  still do not know is how to pass the password so i dont have to enter it!
Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

pscp -pw 'PASSWORD' ${PWD}/SRCFILE root@192.168.0.164:/root/DSTFILE

Comment: A small description of why your answer might work will help the users to understand the concept behind it.